# Mostrar las imagenes de input file JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase,consiste en hacer un drag and drop múltiple, que se visualice los datos y las imagenes y lo único que me falta es poder visualizar las imágenes que subo a ese input, he conseguido hacer que si visualice una, pero claro, cuando subo varías solo se visualiza una. Dejo el código.

```js
function GetFileInfo() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  var archivoRuta = fileInput.value;
  var extPermitidas = /(.PNG|.png|.jpg|.JPG|.JPEG|.jpeg)$/i;
  var message = "";
  if ('files' in fileInput) {
      if (fileInput.files.length == 0 || !extPermitidas.exec(archivoRuta)) {
          message = "Por favor eliga uno o más archivos.";
          if (!extPermitidas.exec(archivoRuta)) {
              message = "Por favor, asegurese de que eliga una imagen";
          }
      } else {
          if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0, 1]) {
              var visor = new FileReader();
              visor.onload = function(e) {
                  document.getElementById('visorArchivo').innerHTML =
                      '<embed src="' + e.target.result + '" width="500" height="375" />';

              };
              visor.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0, 1]);
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
              message += "<br /><b>" + (i + 1) + ". file</b><br />";
              var file = fileInput.files[i];
              if ('name' in file) {
                  message += "Nombre: " + file.name + "<br />";
              } else {
                  message += "Nombre: " + file.fileName + "<br />";
              }
              if ('size' in file) {
                  message += "Tamaño: " + file.size + " bytes <br />";
              } else {
                  message += "Tamaño: " + file.fileSize + " bytes <br />";
              }
              if ('mediaType' in file) {
                  message += "tipo: " + file.mediaType + "<br />";
              }
          }
      }
  } else {
      if (fileInput.value == "") {
          message += "Selecciona una o más imagenes.";
          message += "<br />Use el control o shift para seleccionar varias imagenes";
      } else {
          message += "Tu navegador no soporta el programa";
          message += "<br />Fila seleccionada " + fileInput.value;
      }
  }

  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  info.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
 <body onload="GetFileInfo ()">
    <form>
        <div class="inf__drop-area">
            <span class="inf__btn">Elige imagen</span>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="files" multiple="multiple" size="60" onchange="GetFileInfo ()" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="visorArchivo">
            <!--Aqui se desplegará el fichero-->
        </div>
        <div id="info" style="margin-top:30px"></div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad lo tienes casi hecho, simplemente has de iterar por todos los ficheros como ya haces para mostrar los datos, pero para cargar las imágenes. Este trozo de código:

```
  if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0, 1]) {
      var visor = new FileReader();
      visor.onload = function(e) {
          document.getElementById('visorArchivo').innerHTML =
              '<embed src="' + e.target.result + '" width="500" height="375" />';

      };
      visor.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0, 1]);
  }
```

Tienes que iterarlo:

```js
function GetFileInfo() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
  var archivoRuta = fileInput.value;
  var extPermitidas = /(.PNG|.png|.jpg|.JPG|.JPEG|.jpeg)$/i;
  var message = "";
  if ('files' in fileInput) {
      if (fileInput.files.length == 0 || !extPermitidas.exec(archivoRuta)) {
          message = "Por favor eliga uno o más archivos.";
          if (!extPermitidas.exec(archivoRuta)) {
              message = "Por favor, asegurese de que eliga una imagen";
          }
      } else {
          if (fileInput.files.length ) {
            document.getElementById('visorArchivo').innerHTML='';
              
            for (let i=0; i < fileInput.files.length;i++) {
              let visor = new FileReader();
              visor.onload = function(e) {
                  document.getElementById('visorArchivo').innerHTML +=
                      '<embed src="' + e.target.result + '" width="500" height="375" />';

              };
             
              visor.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
            }
          }
          for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
              message += "<br /><b>" + (i + 1) + ". file</b><br />";
              var file = fileInput.files[i];
              if ('name' in file) {
                  message += "Nombre: " + file.name + "<br />";
              } else {
                  message += "Nombre: " + file.fileName + "<br />";
              }
              if ('size' in file) {
                  message += "Tamaño: " + file.size + " bytes <br />";
              } else {
                  message += "Tamaño: " + file.fileSize + " bytes <br />";
              }
              if ('mediaType' in file) {
                  message += "tipo: " + file.mediaType + "<br />";
              }
          }
      }
  } else {
      if (fileInput.value == "") {
          message += "Selecciona una o más imagenes.";
          message += "<br />Use el control o shift para seleccionar varias imagenes";
      } else {
          message += "Tu navegador no soporta el programa";
          message += "<br />Fila seleccionada " + fileInput.value;
      }
  }

  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  info.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<body onload="GetFileInfo ()">
    <form>
        <div class="inf__drop-area">
            <span class="inf__btn">Elige imagen</span>
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="files" multiple="multiple" size="60" onchange="GetFileInfo ()" />
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div id="visorArchivo">
            <!--Aqui se desplegará el fichero-->
        </div>
        <div id="info" style="margin-top:30px"></div>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había caído!